# How to create a unittest for a function that uses JwtEncoder?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, encoding

I use this code to produce a autorization token.

```
 public string Get(string tenantId, string appId, string appSecret)
{
    const int TimeoutSecs = 1800;
    var tool = new MyDateTimeTool();
    var unixTime = tool.ToUnixTimestamp(m_dateTime);
    var unixTimeExpires = tool.ToUnixTimestamp(m_dateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(TimeoutSecs));
    var jwtClaims = new JwtClaims
    {
        jti = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        iat = unixTime,
        exp = unixTimeExpires,
        iss = "http://cylance.com",
        tid = tenantId,
        sub = appId
    };

    var algorithm = new HMACSHA256Algorithm();
    var serializer = new JsonNetSerializer();
    var encoder = new  JwtBase64UrlEncoder();
    var jwt = new JwtEncoder(algorithm, serializer, encoder);

    return jwt.Encode(jwtClaims, appSecret);
}
```

So I want to create an unittest for this function. This unittest looks like this:

```
string tenantId = "ThisIsATennantId";
string appId = "ThisIsAnAppID";
string appSecret = "ThisIsASecret";
IMyDateTime dateTime = new FakeMyDateTime("17.7.2019 17:22:45");
IAuthorizationTokenGetter getter = new AuthorizationTokenGetter(dateTime);
string token = getter.Get(tenantId,appId,appSecret);
Assert.Equal(token, "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1NjMzNzg3NjUsImlhdCI6MTU2MzM3Njk2NSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2N5bGFuY2UuY29tIiwic3ViIjoiRGFzaXN0ZWluZUFwcElEazk4Nzk4aCIsImp0aSI6ImM2MTZjYzFhLTQ2MDUtNGQzNi1hNDBmLTVjZDQ1YjliNzNjMiIsInRpZCI6IkRhc2lzdGVpbmVUZW5uYW50SUQ4OTkwOGdqZ21tbm4ifQ.kzyTnLKykCA_fKuSOMxaS7SwYkB-08pVcNZeABZSq_E");
```

But the token is always different. So I think the encoder uses a Randomizer or the system time internaly.

So is there a way to tell the Encoder to use a special seed or time so it produces deterministic results? Or do I have to create a Container for the JwtEncoder so that I can fake the results?

Comment: The `Get` method uses the `Guid.NewGuid()`. Of course, each time the value will be new.

Comment: You also create and use time. Presumably, its value is also different every time.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov: You are right. Guid.NewGuid() is something I have to fake. But the Time as "m_dateTime" is already faked (See: new FakeMyDateTime("17.7.2019 17:22:45")).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not the Encoder but the creation of the Guid. So I created a container for the Guid creation so I can fake this too. The unittest looks like this now:

```
string tenantId = "DasisteineTennantID89908gjgmmnn";
string appId = "DasisteineAppIDk98798h";
string appSecret = "DasisteinAppSecret899ahiuhri78789";
IMyDateTime dateTime = new FakeMyDateTime("17.7.2019 17:22:45");
IMyGUIDFactory guidFactory = new FakeMyGUIDFactory("0f889994-f4ea-4db3-9ee3-af40b8313768");
IAuthorizationTokenGetter getter = new AuthorizationTokenGetter(dateTime, guidFactory);
string token = getter.Get(tenantId,appId,appSecret);
Assert.Gleich(token, "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1NjMzNzg3NjUsImlhdCI6MTU2MzM3Njk2NSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2N5bGFuY2UuY29tIiwic3ViIjoiRGFzaXN0ZWluZUFwcElEazk4Nzk4aCIsImp0aSI6IjBmODg5OTk0LWY0ZWEtNGRiMy05ZWUzLWFmNDBiODMxMzc2OCIsInRpZCI6IkRhc2lzdGVpbmVUZW5uYW50SUQ4OTkwOGdqZ21tbm4ifQ.SwkjfpdpHDM1EG1xNVIXaNBrvRVd3wWXr0HLFlJpLSk");
```